# How to extract parent nodes and subsequent nodes from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to solve the following problem. There is a dataframe `df`:

```
df = 

ID  GROUP_1   GROUP_2    GROUP_3    GROUP_4
1   AAA       AAA        BBB        CCC
2   CCC       AAA        CCC        BBB
3   DDD       CCC        BBB        CCC
4   ...
```

I need to extract all sequences of groups and count them. The output should be this one (in squared brackets I want to have all possible subsequent nodes for the given parent node):

```
result =
AAA, 3, [AAA,BBB,CCC]
BBB, 2, [CCC]
CCC, 3, [AAA,BBB]
DDD, 1, [CCC]
```

I know how to count the number of unique occurances of groups as follows:

```
df.filter(regex="^GROUP").stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True).reset_index().drop_duplicates()[0].value_counts()
```

It gives the output like this one:

```
AAA 2
BBB 3
CCC 3
DDD 1
```

However, I don't know how to extract all possible subsequent nodes without duplicates and count all occurances of these pairs (including duplicates).

Comment: I don't get it, how did you get `DDD, 1, [CCC]` line? Or `CCC, 3, [AAA,BBB]` line?

Comment: @RomanPekar: As you can see in `df`, the value `DDD` has only one possible subsequent column's value which is `CCC`, and there is only one occurance of such sequence `<DDD,CCC>` (it occurs in row 3). The same for `CCC`: this value can have two possible unique values of subsequent columns, which are `AAA` and `BBB`, and totally there are 3 occurances of such pairs: `<CCC,AAA>` (row 2), `<CCC, BBB>` (row 2), `<CCC, BBB>` (row 3). Is it more clear now? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option here:

```
# melt data frame to long format
long_df = pd.melt(df, id_vars = "ID", value_name="First")

# create a shifted subsequent nodes column
(long_df.assign(Second = long_df.groupby("ID").First.shift(-1))

# aggregation grouped by the first column
 .groupby('First').Second
 .agg({'Count': 'count', 'Second': lambda x: x.dropna().unique().tolist()}))
```

[image]

---

*Variantions for dealing with missing values:*

**Variation 1**:

`dropna()` after creating the shifted column, this will drop any pair that contains `nan`:

```
(long_df.assign(Second = long_df.groupby("ID").First.shift(-1)).dropna()
 .groupby('First').Second
 .agg({'Count': 'count', 'Second': lambda x: x.unique().tolist()}))
```

**Variation 2**:

Drop missing values in the long format data frame before creating the shifted column, this will connect the non missing values right before missing value with the one after the missing value:

```
(long_df.dropna().assign(Second = long_df.groupby("ID").First.shift(-1))
 .groupby('First').Second
 .agg({'Count': 'count', 'Second': lambda x: x.unique().tolist()}))
```

Comment: What is `First`? Does it correspond to `GROUP_` in my example?

Comment: I renamed the value column to `First` in the `melt`, it corresponds to the values under the `GROUP_` columns but in the long format.

Comment: What if some columns `GROUP_X` have empty values? Will this solution put `NaN` into the list in the column `Second`? How to avoid it? Sorry, I have not mentioned this important point in the question.

Comment: Missing values will be dropped in this case. Do you want something differently? Or if nan is present, then the value before it should not have a subsequent?

Comment: Yes, if, for instance, there is a sequence `DDD`->`NaN`, then it should be ignored.

Comment: this is a nice one

Comment: I added two variations for dealing with missing values, you can check to see which is the one you need.

Answer (score 2):

Get all possible values

```
>>> df.set_index('ID').stack().reset_index(drop=True)
0     AAA
1     AAA
2     BBB
3     CCC
4     CCC
5     AAA
6     CCC
7     BBB
8     DDD
9     CCC
10    BBB
11    CCC
```

Get all subsequent values using [`pandas.DataFrame.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html):

```
>>> df3 = pd.concat([df2, df2.shift(-1)], axis=1)
>>> df3.columns = ['k', 'v']
>>> df3 = df3[df3['v'].notnull()]
>>> df3 = df3.drop_duplicates()
>>> df3
     k    v
0  AAA  AAA
1  AAA  BBB
2  BBB  CCC
3  CCC  CCC
4  CCC  AAA
5  AAA  CCC
6  CCC  BBB
7  BBB  DDD
8  DDD  CCC
```

Aggregate values to lists using [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

```
>>> df3.groupby('k')['v'].apply(list)
k
AAA    [AAA, BBB, CCC]
BBB         [CCC, DDD]
CCC    [BBB, AAA, CCC]
DDD              [CCC]
```

Or

```
>>> df3.groupby('k').apply(lambda x: pd.Series([len(x), list(x['v'])]))
     0                1
k                      
AAA  3  [AAA, BBB, CCC]
BBB  2       [CCC, DDD]
CCC  3  [BBB, AAA, CCC]
DDD  1            [CCC]
```

Comment: Nice. But how do I calculate the number of all occurances for each parent node in order to put it into the final result?

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I accepted the solution of Psidom because it's a bit faster on my dataset.

Comment: @Dinosaurius totally agree that his solution is better